# Identify Stocks With Increasing Trends

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

I have a dataframe in "long" format. The first column contains the date, second the stock name, and last is the closing price. When plotting, this format is pretty simple. You can use the stock name column either to create different colored lines or facet onto separate plots. Great.

Here's the sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1592611200, 1592611200, 1592611200,
                                         1592611200, 1592697600, 1592697600,
                                         1592697600, 1592697600, 1592784000,
                                         1592784000, 1592784000, 1592784000,
                                         1592870400, 1592870400, 1592870400,
                                         1592870400, 1592956800, 1592956800,
                                         1592956800, 1592956800, 1593043200,
                                         1593043200, 1593043200, 1593043200,
                                         1593129600, 1593129600, 1593129600,
                                         1593129600, 1593216000, 1593216000,
                                         1593216000, 1593216000, 1593302400,
                                         1593302400, 1593302400, 1593302400,
                                         1593388800, 1593388800, 1593388800,
                                         1593388800), 
                                       tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                      stock_name = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX",
                                     "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX"), 
                      closing_price = c(200, 1900, 100, 150, 210, 
                                        1950, 90, 160, 211, 1975, 75, 150,
                                        213, 1980, 60, 140, 211, 1990, 50,
                                        150, 213, 1991, 45, 160, 214, 1990,
                                        40, 150, 215, 1998, 38, 140, 217,
                                        2010, 30, 150, 216, 2020, 20, 150)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The goal however, is to identify which of the following stocks have an increasing trend. My thought is to apply a linear model to each stock, then extract the slope and filter based on which ones are positive. The problem I'm having is how to accomplish this with a dataframe in "long" form.

In reality, the dataframe has additional columns that would not really translate well into a "wide" format of dataframe. So, in my mind, it would need to stay in "long" form.

How would you go about identifying which of these stocks has an increasing trend?

Goal dataframe:

```
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1592611200, 1592611200, 1592611200,
                                         1592611200, 1592697600, 1592697600,
                                         1592697600, 1592697600, 1592784000,
                                         1592784000, 1592784000, 1592784000,
                                         1592870400, 1592870400, 1592870400,
                                         1592870400, 1592956800, 1592956800,
                                         1592956800, 1592956800, 1593043200,
                                         1593043200, 1593043200, 1593043200,
                                         1593129600, 1593129600, 1593129600,
                                         1593129600, 1593216000, 1593216000,
                                         1593216000, 1593216000, 1593302400,
                                         1593302400, 1593302400, 1593302400,
                                         1593388800, 1593388800, 1593388800,
                                         1593388800), 
                                       tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                      stock_name = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX",
                                     "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX"), 
                      closing_price = c(200, 1900, 100, 150, 210, 
                                        1950, 90, 160, 211, 1975, 75, 150,
                                        213, 1980, 60, 140, 211, 1990, 50,
                                        150, 213, 1991, 45, 160, 214, 1990,
                                        40, 150, 215, 1998, 38, 140, 217,
                                        2010, 30, 150, 216, 2020, 20, 150),
                      trend = c("increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "",
                                "increasing", "increasing", "", "")),
                 row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
#function to label a trend as increasing
label_increasing <- function(stck_df){
  mdl <- lm(closing_price ~ Date, data = stck_df)
  #create a model using the date as a predictor
  if(mdl$coefficients["Date"] > 0){
    return("increasing")
    #if the trend is increasing with date, return "increasing"
  }#end if
}#end function

apple_dat <- dat %>%
  filter(stock_name == "AAPL")
#filter just the apple stock

apple_label <- label_increasing(filtered_dat)
apple_label
#works for a single stock

labeled_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(stock_name) %>%
  mutate(trend = label_increasing(.))
labeled_dat
#does not work for the full data frame

labeled_dat <- dat %>%
  group_by(stock_name) %>%
  mutate(trend = map(., label_increasing))
labeled_dat
#I have a feeling I need to do some mapping but this isn't quite right
```

Lastly, the inspiration for this is the NYT Covid-19 dashboard. The section on which states are increasing and decreasing. Found [here](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/coronavirus-us-cases.html?action=click&pgtype=Article&state=default&module=styln-coronavirus&variant=show&region=TOP_BANNER&context=storylines_menu).

Comment: Over what period do you want to trend?

Comment: For this example, it would be the min and max dates of the data frame. In other words, the whole time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `nest` the data for each `stock_name` and map your function to each group.

Edit: I had to modify `label_increasing()` so the response variable was named `closing_price`.

```
library(tidyverse)

label_increasing <- function(stck_df){
  mdl <- lm(closing_price ~ Date, data = stck_df)
  #create a model using the date as a predictor
  if(mdl$coefficients["Date"] > 0){
    return("increasing")
    #if the trend is increasing with date, return "increasing"
  } #end if
}#end function

dat %>%
  group_by(stock_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(trend = map(data, label_increasing)) %>%
  unnest(trend)


#-----

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   stock_name [2]
  stock_name data              lm_mod    
  <chr>      <list>            <chr>     
1 AAPL       <tibble [10 x 3]> increasing
2 AMZN       <tibble [10 x 3]> increasing
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for! One slight change I've made: instead of unnest(trend), I used unnest(data). This gets it back to the original DF with the addition of the labeled trend column. Ohh and thanks for catching my typo. I updated my code to include your edit (the closing_price)

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want the whole period let's start them all the same and track growth or percent growth then you can use a simple filter statement to chose to show only those that grew beginning to end no matter how small

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% group_by(stock_name) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  mutate(growth = closing_price - first(closing_price), 
         growth_percent = (closing_price - first(closing_price))/first(closing_price)*100) %>%
  filter(last(growth) >= 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = growth, group = stock_name, color = stock_name)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Your original data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1592611200, 1592611200, 1592611200,
                                         1592611200, 1592697600, 1592697600,
                                         1592697600, 1592697600, 1592784000,
                                         1592784000, 1592784000, 1592784000,
                                         1592870400, 1592870400, 1592870400,
                                         1592870400, 1592956800, 1592956800,
                                         1592956800, 1592956800, 1593043200,
                                         1593043200, 1593043200, 1593043200,
                                         1593129600, 1593129600, 1593129600,
                                         1593129600, 1593216000, 1593216000,
                                         1593216000, 1593216000, 1593302400,
                                         1593302400, 1593302400, 1593302400,
                                         1593388800, 1593388800, 1593388800,
                                         1593388800), 
                                       tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
                      stock_name = c("AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX",
                                     "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL",
                                     "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN",
                                     "HTZ", "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ",
                                     "NFLX", "AAPL", "AMZN", "HTZ", "NFLX"), 
                      closing_price = c(200, 1900, 100, 150, 210, 
                                        1950, 90, 160, 211, 1975, 75, 150,
                                        213, 1980, 60, 140, 211, 1990, 50,
                                        150, 213, 1991, 45, 160, 214, 1990,
                                        40, 150, 215, 1998, 38, 140, 217,
                                        2010, 30, 150, 216, 2020, 20, 150)),
                 row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# dat
```

Comment: Clearly, I was overthinking a solution. This would work for the question I asked and is simpler. I would lean towards the above answer only because, in my opinion, it seems less sensitive to individual closing prices. That's far beyond the question I asked though, so blame my question asking skills.

Comment: Percent growth is also probably a better indicator but that is a simple change in the code

Answer (score 0):

Visualize the data with ggplot, and have a look!

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dat) + 
    geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Date, y = closing_price)) + 
    facet_wrap(~stock_name, scales = "free_y")
```

[image: ggplot output]

This is in answer to your question **How would you go about identifying which of these stocks has an increasing trend?** (If you want a financial analysis, I suggest hiring someone.)

Comment: Hahaha I'm certainly not looking for financial analysis. My portfolio would look like Hertz. What I am after though is being able to label trends as either increasing or decreasing without having to visualize them. Imagine a dashboard where it highlights all the stocks in your profile that are trending up and doesn't show stocks that are flat or decreasing. I've added some code above that might better illustrate what I'm after. But nice code for visualizing!